# Can I license my controller for a KotH under the GNU GPL v3?

Tags: discussion, king-of-the-hill

I've just finished making a controller for a KotH challenge, and I wanted to know: Can I use it for the KotH and license it under the GNU GPL v3, or does it have to be licensed with the MIT License to be used for a KotH on CGCC?

Comment: One thing to note: if you release your controller code here (i.e. in the question body, which you shouldn't), it becomes licensed under [CC-BY-SA](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), as with all code on the network

Comment: No. I'm going to provide a link to its GitHub repo.

Comment: Also, no matter what license you choose. Answers here (as long as they posted it on SE sites) would automatically licensed under [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) which is [compatible with GPLv3](https://www.fsf.org/blogs/licensing/creative-commons-by-sa-4-0-declared-one-way-compatible-with-gnu-gpl-version-3).

Comment: Just a note, I don't think GPL licensing is particularly useful here. I doubt any companies are likely to want to make profit off your KotH controllers :p

Comment: I know, but I just want to make sure in case it ever turns out to be useful for anybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You can license it however you wish offsite

The important (but still not necessary) part is that people can run it. Preferably the source should be shared for easier testing and for malware protection.

## On-site, code is licensed under CC-BY-SA 4.0

This applies to controllers you post in the question, but it's probably not a good idea to put it there (e.g. if the controller includes the code for the submissions, which is bad for the same reason as leaderboards).